# How do I get topshelf to return error code when command fails?

Tags: powershell, topshelf

I am trying to start my service with powershell but currently it fails. I don't know why it fails but that is not the point here. When trying to start the host all I don't get the correct exit code so my automatic deploy fails silently.

What I'm trying to do is:

```
$cmd = "$folder" + "\MyService.exe"
try
{
    & $cmd stop
    & $cmd uninstall
    & $cmd install
    & $cmd start
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Error: Update of service failed"
    exit 1
}
```

The `start` command fails with the following messge:

```
Topshelf.Hosts.StartHost Error: 0 : The service failed to start., System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start service MyService on computer '.'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
    at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start()
    at Topshelf.Runtime.Windows.WindowsHostEnvironment.StartService(String serviceName)
    at Topshelf.Hosts.StartHost.Run()
```

and I never get into the catch statement of my powershell script.

**UPDATE:**

Note that I am asking for how to get the method to the catch statement and not the solution to the actual exception. I have solved the actual exception but I want better feedback in the future if it fails, and that is want the catch statement to be executed which it isn't in case of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`try/catch` in PowerShell doesn't work with exe.
After `myservice.exe` calls you need to check the automatic variable `$LastExitCode`.
Try something like this:

```
$out = & $cmd start
if ($LastExitCode -ne 0) # if exe returns 0 on success, if not change the condition accordingly
{
    "ERROR: $out"
    return # to exit script or do something else.
}
```

Comment: I have tried that as well, it didn't work. I don't think the last exit code is set correctly.

Comment: The value of ´$LastExitCode´ was set to 0.

Comment: um.. I think exit code is not set in the executable code. You can try check if `$out -match 'error'` as workaround...

Comment: I've thought about a workround like that. I'll see if someone else has it figured out first. Thanks.

Comment: I think you forgot to return the exit code in your console application. HostFactory.Run returns a TopshelfExitCode enum value which should be returned by the main method of your console app.

Comment: as mentioned by @SvenSchelfaut, here is the code that worked for me 
    var exitCode = HostFactory.Run(x =>
        {
        ...
        });
    Environment.Exit((int)exitCode);

Comment: If the console app writes its error to the error stream then it can be caught by a try/catch e.g. `Console.Error.WriteLine("Something really bad happened");`